# Trying to connect Google Vision AI to Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, vision-api

On my Django website the user is able to upload images. I am trying to implement a feature for them to search for images based on what the images are.

To do this I decided to use Google Vision AI. I was able to get this API to work in a separate project. However, when I try implementing the API into my Django project it doesn't work. (Error pasted at the end).

In my **test project** I had to create an environment variable for the Google Application Credentials, this is what it looked like:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'venv/filename.json'
```

After reading several articles on how to implement environment variables into Django, this is what I implemented thus far into **settings.py:**

```
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
```

As a test to see if environment variables were working at all in my project, I stored the SECRET_KEY into the .env file and I got it to work. Here is what that looked like along with my .env file

**.env**

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=venv/filename.json
SECRET_KEY=this-is-my-secret##key
```

**SECRET_KEY:**

```
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

**The error I am getting:**

```
DefaultCredentialsError at /images/
File venv/filename.json was not found.
```

**Please help me to figure out why my environment variable is not working**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my program was that I was searching for the environment key in the wrong directory. Once I moved the file to the proper directory/ changed directory through my code all was well.